# Number Square Looping - Java

Tags: java, for-loop

I wanted it to look only this:

```
1 2 3 4 5
2 3 4 5 4
3 4 5 4 3
4 5 4 3 2
5 4 3 2 1
```

but ends up:

```
1 2 3 4 5
2 3 4 5 4 3 2 1
3 4 5 4 3 2 1
4 5 4 3 2 1
5 4 3 2 1
```

Here's my code:

```
for(int a = 1; a <= 5; a++){
    for(int b = a; b <=5; b++){
        System.out.print(b+ " ");
    }
    if(a != 1){
        for(int c = 4; c >= 1; c--){    
            for(int d = c; d == c; d--){
                System.out.print(d + " ");  
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println();   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your inner `for` loop doesn't look good. Try this:

```
for(int a = 1; a <= 5; a++){
    for(int b = a; b <=5; b++){
        System.out.print(b+ " ");
    }
    for(int c = 4; c >= 6-a; c--){
        System.out.print(c + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Note: you also don't need the `if(a != 1)` check any longer, as the second (inner) `for` loop is only executed for `2 <= a <= 5`
(as `a` cannot be more than 5 because of the outer `for`)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 for(int a = 1; a <= 5; a++){
    int numberByLine=5;
        for(int b = a; b <=5; b++){
            System.out.print(b+ " ");
numberByLine--;
        }
        if(a != 1){
            for(int c = 4; numberByLine!=0; c--){    
                    System.out.print(c + " ");
numberByLine--;
            }
        }
            System.out.println();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I removed the a!=1 check to make it cleaner
Added a maxval variable so you can make different-sized squares

```
int maxval = 5;
for(int a = 1; a <= maxval; a++){
    for(int b = a; b <= maxval; b++){
        System.out.print(b+ " ");
    }
    for(int c = (maxval-1); c > (maxval-a); c--){    
        System.out.print(c + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```